# Hibernate dosen't save ElementCollections

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

For some reason Hibernate does not save any of the elementCollections

```
@Entity
@Proxy(lazy = false)
@Table(name = "PRE_FUND", schema = "ADMIN")

public class Fund implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private long id;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name="PRE_FOLIO", schema = "ADMIN", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID"))
private List<String> folio;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="PRE_TYPE", schema = "ADMIN", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID"))
private List<String> type;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name="PRE_INST", schema = "ADMIN", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID"))
private List<String> inst;

}
```

is the entity with collections.

And then i have method for saving the entities.

```
for(Fund funds : a){
        repo.save(funds);
    }
```

Debugger shows that there is 26 entries going into this for loop, with elements in every collection.

However tables will stay empty and no error is thrown.

Later on the appliation will crash with null pointer exception thanks to this...

EDIT: the Fund object will be saved, but the Element collections will stay empty.

Comment: I can suggest to try to create `@Embeddable` entities and use them in your collections.

Comment: I would not like to divide these 3 to yet another set of entities. There is 2 classes like this, which would add 6 entities just for this one thing on top of already huge set of entities. I'd really reall prefere to get this to work. Otherwise i think i have to use @Embedded

Comment: You can use single `@Embedded` entity for this.

Comment: Still, that seems to call for quite a lot refactoring of code.. I would really like to know why this solution is not usable since it seems like really basic idea. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Try to add `@Column(name="value")` to your fields.

Comment: Added Columns to all the collection, nothing changed..

Comment: Then I don't know :(

Comment: Thanks anyways for all the help. im beginning to think using Hibernate is very bad idea... Been using weeks on solving problems that dosent even seem like problems, like this one...

Comment: Usually hibernate is not that bad, but if you try something that is rarely used it can be real pain in the ass. If you don't have someone experienced to help you it may be reasonable to switch to something simpler(JDBC). But at other side if you manage to solve all that problem you become very useful expert :)